# How to add a button to a form from another form? C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, pos

I am currently developing a POS (Point of Sale) system for use in restaurants. I have made a user interface where you would add a new menu item to a list of buttons on another form. I want the details entered on 1 form to create a new menu item Button in another form. if this makes sense. I also want the user interface to add button name, category(eg.pizza, pasta), and price. I am using c# Winforms on Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't be a proper design if FormA would directly change the layout of FormB. It would be better to let FormA kindly ask FormB to add the button, or maybe even simpler: to show the button.

```
class FormB
{
    private Button myButton;

    public bool MyButtonVisible
    {
        get => this.myButton.Visible;
        set => this.myButton.Visible = value;
    }

    ...
```

If showing the button needs more code:

```
public void MakeMyButtonVisible()
{
     ... // thing you have to do before my button becomes visible
     this.myButton.Visible = true;
}
```

Usage:

```
class FormA
{
     // apparently FormA knows about FormB:
     private FormB { get => ...}

     private void ShowButtonOnFormB()
     {
          // maybe some code to make sure FormB is shown
          this.FormB.MakeMyButtonVisible();
     }

     private void OnMenuItem_ShowMyButton_Clicked(object sender, ...)
     {
          this.ShowBuffonFormB();
     }
}
```